# The matrix in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $A^{**}$ be the double adjoint of $A$. Can we conclude $M_{n}(A^{**})\cong (M_{n}(A))^{**}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for all $C^*$ algebras, see paragraph 2.2.11 [in this lecture notes](http://www.math.uh.edu/~dblecher/op.pdf) by D. P. Blecher.

Comment: I am sorry, after reading the relevant content in the lecture notes you mentioned above, I am still confused with the proof in the notes. Could you give me a outline or some hints of this question?

Comment: If you do not familiar with operator spaces it would take too much time to explain.

Comment: these lecture notes are no longer available, could you please at least summarize the heart of the argument

Comment: @Clclstdnt, then take a look at theorem 1.4.11 [here](http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/academic/pdf/13/9780198526599.pdf)

Comment: Thank you!   What text does this come from?  By the way, it reads a lot like him, are these his notes?

Comment: @Clclstdnt, take a look at his book Operator Algebras and their modules. It is more like a reference book, rather than a textbook.